# Can I use gc.collect()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

**TLDR:** Adding a `gc.collect()` to my script has fixed the memory leak. How did this happen?

---

**Long version:** I was having a memory leak in my Flask server, after making a change in how the databases is updated. Before the change, the server processes would have a resident set size of 28kB. After applying the change, it would grow up to 250 Mb in two days.

I've did some tests with the heap, but I didn't get any clue where the dangling references might be. So I just added a `gc.collect()` after the database commit (which happens every 15 sec).

This somehow mysteriously solved it, because it has been running for an hour now and it stays below 29.5kb (before the fix it would be way higher now). I'm not sure why this change would solve this, since Python has automatic GC, and I'm just forcing an immediate one. Is using `gc.collect()` a viable solution for fixing the leak (e.g. no side-effects)?

Comment: May I assume that your code does not contain `gc.disable()`?

Comment: No other `gc` related calls in the code.

Comment: `gc.collect()` does not have logical side-effects, it can however be "slow". It may be noticeable as a response time spike (say 1 request of of 1000 is slower by NNms), depending on amount of live objects.

Comment: Ok, that won't be a problem. But why does it solve the leak if there's an automatic GC?

Comment: That I cannot answer; `gc.collect()` (by default with generation 2), is already ran by Python every NNNN allocations. There's no obvious reason for explicit call to "fix" your code. https://pymotw.com/2/gc/ has some practical approaches if you want to debug further.

Comment: Yeah I've been through that article, but I couldn't find anything useful (mostly just HTTP cache)